# The address of the reference variable and the address of the object

Tags: python

I would appreciate you people helping me in the following:

How to print the address of a reference variable and the address of an object in Python.
I know we can print the address of an object like that `print(id(variable))` but in this way I just get the address of the object but not the reference variable. As I have learned in C++ that reference variable has difference memory address and the value of the reference variable is actually the address of an object (if I am not wrong). I actually want to see the address of the reference variable and the address of the actual object which is created in the execution time.

Comment: C++ and Python are completely different programming languages that work in completely different ways. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?  Python doesn't let you operate on raw memory the way C++ does, so concepts like memory addresses only make sense in the context of the language implementation, not the language itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! if python allows me to use a variable which is pointing to the particular object and i can also find out the memory adress of that particular object  with the help of id() function which returns me the actual adress of the object. Then why i can not try to find out the memory adress of a variable of my choice? Thanks

Comment: There is no guarantee that the integer returned by `id` is a memory address. The concept simply does not exist in Python. For all you know, every object is stored in a SQL database, not memory, and is retrieved using a `SELECT` query every time you request its value.

Comment: Just because Python uses references does not mean those references are pointers.

Comment: Adding to the previous comments, the offical documentation for [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#id) states: *"Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory."* - so you were relying on an implementation detail, which may change anytime

Comment: Even in the CPython case, where the id is derived from a memory address, *only* the object has an id. The variable does not have any sort of concrete existence; it's just a name in some internal hash table that maps to an object. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: When you write something like `i = "hello"`, that creates a string object in object space, which is anonymous.  An object has NO IDEA what names have been bound to it.  And in the case of a global, there isn't even an independent thing called `i`.  Instead, `i` is a key in the dictionary of global variables.  There just is no fundamental space of variable names, like you have in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

The "reference variables" you're referring to don't exist in Python.

Python variables are essentially entries in a namespace. They are basically just "names" that are bound to an object. These "names" are not in and of themselves objects, they have no "address" in the Python virtual machine, they don't exist as entities in that way.

These reading materials may help:

- [Is Python call by reference or call by value - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/#:%7E:text=Python%20utilizes%20a%20system%2C%20which,being%20passed%20to%20the%20function).
- [Pass by Reference in Python: Background and Best Practices – Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/)
- [Is Python pass-by-reference or pass-by-value? | Robert Heaton](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)
- [Is Python Call by Value or Call by Reference? | by Lokesh sharma | Medium](https://medium.com/@lokeshsharma596/is-python-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference-2dd7db74dbd0)